# I'm trying to make a mobile web app that displays the location , but it ain't working?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html5-canvas

I'm new to stack overflow , I signed up since I ran into an error.
This is for my upcoming high school project !

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="button" value="Result" onclick="getGeolocation" />
    <input type="button" value="Result" onclick="getUserCoodinates" />
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
    //run this code when the page loads
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      getGeolocation();
    });
    //determine if the user's browser has location services enabled. If not, show a message
    function getGeolocation() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        //if location services are turned on, continue and call the getUserCoordinates function below
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getUserCoodinates);
      } else {
        alert('You must enable your device\'s location services in order to run this application.');
      }
    }
    //function is passed a position object which contains the lat and long value
    function getUserCoodinates(position) {
      //set the application's text inputs LAT and LONG = to the user's lat and long position
      jQuery("#LAT").val(position.coords.latitude);
      jQuery("#LONG").val(position.coords.longitude);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Where have I gone wrong ? ? ?

I'm trying to use this for a mobile web-app.

Comment: The geolocation api is only avaiable when a SSL certificate is activated on the webserver/domain

Comment: `getUserCoodinates` needs the `position` as the only supplied argument - using the `onclick` as you do here will fail as the `position` is obtained by the geolocation callback so essentially `<input type="button" value="Result" onclick="getUserCoodinates"/>` is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

In your code `getUserCoodinates` is a callback function so it should not be invoked directly using a button click so that portion of the HTML can be removed. As per the comment from @Darkbee - the webserver should be running the page over SSL/https otherwise this will fail.

The second argument that you can supply to `getCurrentPosition` is for processing errors - seems to make sense here to use that to try to identify the issue. The following runs perfectly on my test system which does run ssl with a `self-signed` certificate.

```js
document.querySelector('[type="button"]').addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
  if( navigator.geolocation ){

    const getUserCoodinates=(pos)=>{
      $('#LAT').val(pos.coords.latitude);
      $('#LONG').val(pos.coords.longitude);
    };

    const showError=(error)=>{
      let msg='An unknown error occurred.';
      switch( error.code ) {
      case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
        msg='User denied the request for Geolocation.'
      break;
      case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
        msg='Location information is unavailable.'
      break;
      case error.TIMEOUT:
        msg='The request to get user location timed out.'
      break;
      default:break;
      }
      alert(msg);
    };


    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getUserCoodinates,showError);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<form>
  <input id='LAT' />
  <input id='LONG' />
  <input type='button' value='Result' />
</form>
```